# How to send email in codeigintier?

Tags: codeigniter

I have done a code for send email to a emailid in codeigniter as shown below :

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Data extends CI_Model
{
 function __construct()
 {
      // Call the Model constructor
      parent::__construct();
 }

 function insertStu($newStuData){
    $stuData = array(
        'stu_fullname' => $newStuData['stuFullname'],
        'stu_username' => $newStuData['stuUsername'],
        'stu_password' => $newStuData['stuPassword'],
        'stu_email' => $newStuData['stuEmail'],
        'stu_modified_date' => date('y-m-d')
    );
     $from_email = "annanitababu.19@gmail.com"; 
     $to_email = $newStuData['stuEmail']; 

     //Load email library 
     $this->load->library('email'); 

     $this->email->from($from_email, 'Anu'); 
     $this->email->to($to_email);
     $this->email->subject('Email Test'); 
     $this->email->message('Testing the email class.');         
     $this->email->send();
     $this->db->insert('sb_stu', $stuData);
     return ($this->db->affected_rows() == 1) ? true : false;        
    }    

   }
  ?>
```

I wanted to send a link of a page as the contents of the message in the send() as a mail to the email id and upon clicking the link in the mail, it should update a particular field in a table which is initially '0' to '1' in the database. Can anyone suggest a solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Add link to in the message body and generate encoded unique identification number . The number in link and stored in your db. The user click on that link , decode the unique and match in the table. if found change status 0 to 1.

Example : https://www.amazonsoldout.com/

which also in codeigniter.